# Does app widget extension need a separate provision profile?

Tags: widgetkit

Does app widget extension need a separate provision profile ?

When I add an Widget extension(if I want to manager the code sign manually in Xcode), do I need to create a new provision profile beside the app's provision profile on

https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list

Or, how can I include the Widget extension in the app's provision profile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For distribution App Widget Extension.

I do need a `separate distribution profile` with `different bundle id too` to distribution successfully.

Both `extension bundle id` & `extension profile` need to create manually on apple's developer site.

If there's ones created by Xcode. just delete it, and create manually.

The ones `created by Xcode can debug` on devices, But `not work when distribution` the app.